# What is the underlying transport mechanism in "ballistic transport"?

Tags: electronics, nanoscience

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_conduction):

> Ballistic conduction or Ballistic transport is the transport of
>   electrons in a medium having negligible electrical resistivity caused
>   by scattering. Without scattering, **electrons simply obey Newton's
>   second law** of motion at non-relativistic speeds. [...] Ballistic
>   transport is **observed when the mean free path of the electron is
>   (much) longer than the dimension of the medium** through which the
>   electron travels.

So is "ballistic transport" another way of saying "tunnelling"?

Comment: It is the same mechanism as regular resistive conduction - acceleration by electric field. In resistive conduction, the atoms/lattice keep interrupting the constant acceleration that the electrons would have undergone instead, restarting the acceleration process. Reduce the source of those interruptions such that they happen after the electrons travel centimetres instead of nanometres, and you have ballisticity.

Answer (score 2):

No it is completely different from tunnelling. Tunnelling is not possible in the classical limit, ballistic transport is!

Ballistic transport is, as text says when the motion of the electrons is approximately following the classical laws of motion. That is, their mean positions fly through the lattice like balls through the air. This happens, as the quote states, if the mean free path is long compared to the dimension of the object (because then there will be, on average, no scattering event over the length).

Note, that electrons can move without resistance in a defect-free crystal lattice, therefore this kind of motion is possible without any tunnelling. Being bound in a crystal lattice will even lower the energy of the electron when compared to being outside the crystal lattice (otherwise electrons would simply fly out of metals, but in the photoelectric effect we observe a limiting wavelength below which no free electrons are observed, the energy of that wavelength corresponds to the electron's binding energy in the lattice).

There are some subtle quantum mechanical effects (an electron's mean position in a crystal will oscillate in DC voltage in the absence of scattering). And sometimes such semi-classical "ballistic" transport is also called ballistic transport.

So the "underlying transport mechanism" of ballistic transport is ballistic motion (i.e. "free" motion without scattering) of the (quasi-)particles in question through the object.

Comment: So "ballistic transport" is a separate thing on its own? I mean, it's not an "umbrella term" for several combined phenomena?

Comment: It is not a thing on its own. It is a certain limit case of transport processes.

Comment: Could you please specify which transport processes?

Comment: In the end, there is but one transport process: Motion of (quasi-)particles.